# concatenate json obj with array

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
{data:something}{data:something}{data:something}{data:something}{data:something}
```

what I want is concatenate an array before each object, like this

```
array = ['a','b','c','d'];

var data = {
a:{data:something}
b:{data:something}
c:{data:something}
d:{data:something}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a JSON object... Can you post your code so far?

Comment: Is what you're starting with actually an array `[]` of those objects `{}` as in `[{data:something},{data:something},...{data:something}]`

Comment: is this a Javascript or PHP question?

Answer (score 0):

**Concatenate two json Arrays**

```
var jsonArray1 = [{'name': "value11", 'id':5}, {'name': "value12", 'id':23}];
var jsonArray2 = [{'name': "value21", 'id':1}, {'name': "value22", 'id':52}];
jsonArray1 = jsonArray1.concat(jsonArray2);
// jsonArray1 = [{'name': "value11", 'id':5}, {'name': "value12", 'id':23}, 
//{'name': "value21", 'id':1}, {'name': "value22", 'id':52}];
```

**Concatenate two json Objects**

```
var json1 = [{id:1, name: 'object1' ...}]
var json2 = [{id:2, name: 'object2' ...}]
var finalObj = json1.concat(json2);
```

**Alternate you can try merge**

```
var finalObj = $.merge(json1, json2);
```

you can use similar technique to concatenate different Objects ( array, custom objects, etc... )

Look at this [webhelp](http://www.jsonexample.com/) .. will be useful to you as well